# What's the format of the @timestamp variable in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to write a routine that will find the latest report published by *SQL Server Reporting Services*. I know the filename and that it'll contain the `@timestamp` variable, but I cannot find what's its format and the customer hasn't provided any test files yet. Do you know whether it's an `int` or a `datetime` etc?

Microsoft doesn't reveal it in its documentation here where it's mentioned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/file-share-delivery-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk_file_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@timestamp` subscription variable is in `yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss` format, as you can see from this example tutorial: https://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/07/ssrs-how-to-create-ssrs-report-with.html